# How to block routing to a page in the public folder

Tags: node.js, routes, public-folders

I'm trying to design my NodeJS application, but there is something I am confused about.

In my application, I plan to put all of the frontend material in the folder `/public` and then put the line

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

in my `app.js` file.

So with this in place, the user will be able to go to `thesite.com/gallery/stuff` and it will work because the `gallery` folder is in `/public`.

**But** what if I don't want the user to be able to visit this area? How can I intercept his request and make sure he is logged in, for example? Is there a way to make some parts of the public folder not so public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a router right before it

```
app.all('/gallery/*', function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.user) next(new Error('You shall not pass!'));
    else next();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```